# Cant uncheck checkbox after adding this jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox

The code is supposed to disable a group of checkboxes. There are two classes of checkbox, if I click on one, it disables the other. The problem is if I change my mind and want to unchoose (uncheck), it does not allow me to uncheck.

```
$(".single-checkbox").click(function(){
      if ($(this).prop("checked", "checked")) {
          $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', true);
     } else {
          // $(this).prop("unchecked", "unchecked")
          // $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', false);      
          // $(".single-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
      }
});
```

I have tried various things in the else part of the statement but no luck. 
Would you have any ideas? There are a couple of questions on unchecking checkboxes and i tried variations in my code but no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the value instead of checking it in the if statement.

```
if ($(this).prop("checked", "checked")) {
```

Instead, you should check if the checkbox is checked.

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: Thank you, this did it, if i unchecked the other class remained disables so i did it like this and it unchecks and undisables.

`$(".single-checkbox").click(function(){

if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       
 $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', true);
     
} else {

          $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', false);
   }
});
`

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).prop("checked", "checked")` statement will set the value of property `checked` and as `"checked"` will evaluate to truthy it will always be `checked`.

These statements can be used,

```
if(this.checked) {
if($(this).is(":checked")){
if($(this).prop("checked")){
```

However you can use *Script*

```
$(".single-checkbox").change(function(){
    $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: `$('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', this.checked);` will not the targeted input controls to be disables. The user agent should check whether the `disabled` attribute is present or not and it does not matter what value is assigned to it. So `disabled="false"` should yet be interpreted as disabled according to W3C spec.

Comment: @IgweKalu, W3C spec are correct You are missing the point its setting the property not attribute value. See docs  http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2 and also go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: I just meant to point out that `$('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', this.checked);` will not toggle disable/enable the input control as I suspect you mean it to.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).prop("checked", "checked")` ensures that the checkbox is always checked whenever it's clicked.

If you want to determine that a checkbox is checked, do this instead:
`if ($(this).prop("checked"))`

Explaining the behaviour you observed in your code:

```
if ($(this).prop("checked", "checked")) {
    $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

`$(this).prop("checked", "checked")` returns an object, which is truthy. This means `$('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', true);` gets executed whatever the case may be. And this means the elements with class `deleteDone` always get disabled.

Comment: thank you everyone for your help. the explanations were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think after clicked on checkbox, the all checkbox will disabled bcoz class `.deleteDone`, therefor you not allow to click again. you need to disabled false for clicked checkbox

```
  $(".single-checkbox").click(function(){
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', true);
            // Add this //
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
         } else {
            //$(this).prop("unchecked", "unchecked")
            //$('.deleteDone').prop('disabled', false);

            //$(".single-checkbox").prop("checked", false);
          }
    });
```

Comment: why should `$(this).removeAttr('disabled');` be added?

Comment: @IgweKalu .. Since no HTML is provided, I assumed all checkboxes to have `.deleteDone` class. If user checks any checkbox, it too will get disabled along others; so to prevent this `$(this).removeAttr('disabled');` was added

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.single-checkbox, .deleteDone').click(function(){ // if you click any of the classes
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked'); // true or false

    if (isChecked) {
        var cbToDisable = $(this).attr('class') == 'single-checkbox' ? 'deleteDone' : 'single-checkbox'; // disable the other class
        $(cbToDisable).prop('disabled', isChecked); // do it
    }
});
```